# Did not get an example "Become the richest" from Solidity documentation

Tags: solidity

I'm reading the common patterns in solidity documentation (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/common-patterns.html#withdrawal-from-contracts) and faced with a problem. I do not understand either the contract has an error or I do not understand correctly how it works. In my opinion it does the following things:

1. The one who sent biggest value becomes richest
2. Other guys can withdraw their deposits
3. The richest also can withdraw its deposit but it is still the richest

But why we use `pendingWithdrawals[richest] += msg.value;` in the function `becomeRichest()` ? So we literally send all money that other guys send to the richest guy? What is the purpose?

Is the statement  correct? And why we do not use `pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender] += msg.value;`?

````
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract WithdrawalContract {
    address public richest;
    uint public mostSent;

    mapping (address => uint) pendingWithdrawals;

    /// The amount of Ether sent was not higher than
    /// the currently highest amount.
    error NotEnoughEther();

    constructor() payable {
        richest = msg.sender;
        mostSent = msg.value;
    }

    function becomeRichest() public payable {
        if (msg.value <= mostSent) revert NotEnoughEther();

        // should it be pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender] += msg.value; instead?
        pendingWithdrawals[richest] += msg.value; 

        richest = msg.sender;
        mostSent = msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        uint amount = pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender];
        // Remember to zero the pending refund before
        // sending to prevent re-entrancy attacks
        pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender] = 0;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }
}```
````

Comment: The code is correct. It's a "kind of the hill" game (google for other discussions). Basically a Ponzi scheme where you deposit an amount hoping that someone else later deposits a greater amount, so you make a profit. Technically `becomeRichest()` should be named `becomePoorestUntilSomeoneElseJoins()`

Comment: @0xSanson thank you very much!